# Solarwinds API SSL cert not able to verify

Tags: python-3.x, solar

According to this post I should def verify the cert.

https://thwack.solarwinds.com/product-forums/the-orion-platform/f/orion-sdk/35763/ssl-certificate-verification-or-not

however, when I do generate the cert with

```
openssl s_client -connect server:17778
```

and put the content: to a file to server.pem.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

conentsff.....

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

and run the test script that looks something like this:

```
swis = orionsdk.SwisClient("servername", username.strip(), password, verify="server.pem")
swis.query("SELECT uri From Orion.Nodes WHERE NodeID=2054")
```

I get the following error:

**`TTPSConnectionPool(host='servername', port=17778): Max retries exceeded with url: /SolarWinds/InformationService/v3/Json/Query (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:897)'),))`**

my guess is that I do not have the right port!! but not 100% sure, please help!

**note**: I know that I can bypass the warning but I want to get the cert to work!